# Angular 2 dynamic component two-way binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, dynamic-compilation

Please help me to find out how to make a two way data binding from parent to dynamically created component.

Here is parent component part:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let factory: ComponentFactory<any> = 
    this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.ComponentType); 
  this._Component = this._viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
  this._Component.instance.Value = this.Value;
  this._Component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // What does it do? :(
}
```

Dynamically created component:

```
@Input() Value: any; // But I think @Input decorator is useless here?
```

Any changes of Value in parent or child do not affect each other.
For me it's not surprising I don't see any line of code that makes data binding.

Please help me or give me a right way to dig.

Thank you.